# Python QGIS : Adding features to a temp vector layer with their attributes

Tags: pyqgis-3, qgis-3

I try to create a temporary vector layer with data from another vector layer that are inside a polygon.
My code works perfectly except that in the temp vector layer, the fields of the attribute table are all empty and I can't figure how to fix this.
The fields of my temporary vectory layer are the same as in the layer with my data.

```
def site(site):
 import processing
 #Creating the temp vector layer
 df_site = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:2154', 'polygon' , 'memory')
 #Selection of the polygon
 perim = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('perimetre_exposition')[0]
 it = perim.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( QgsExpression( "\"Site\"=' {}'".format(site))))
 ids = [i.id() for i in it]
 site = perim.getFeature(ids[0])
 perim_site = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:2154', 'polygon' , 'memory')
 perim_site.dataProvider().addFeature(site)


 df_site.startEditing()
 #Vector layer including my data (named bats)
 bats = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('batiments_landuse_48sites')[0]
 #Adding the fields from the layer with my data to the temp layer
 for i in bats.dataProvider().fields():
     df_site.addAttribute(i)

 bats.removeSelection()
 processing.run("native:selectbylocation",{'INPUT': bats,'PREDICATE': 0, 'INTERSECT': perim_site, 'METHOD':0})
 bats_site = bats.getSelectedFeatures()
 df_site.dataProvider().addFeatures(bats_site)
 del(bats,bats_site)
 QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(df_site)
```